Personality change in violent psychopath waiting to be executed.
I'm looking for this movie for a long time. Psychopath with uncontrollable urge to violence condemned to death waiting to execution. Psychologist offering him to participate in experiment where him memory from childhood has been deleted and he became another person at all. If I remember correctly than they trying to rescue him from execution after it. Possible it was movie by John Travolta but I may be wrong.

"Possible it was movie by John Travolta" - By or with?

I think with, but after answers I've received I'm not sure.

Ah, sounds like Identity with John Cusack.
See trailer below:


 
And if it isn't then I suggest watching Identity anyway.

Can I second that...identity is an awesome film.

Well, awesome film, but doesn't sound too likely. But ok, it's worth a try.

Every description given features in this film, the trailer doesn't show it but it is all there, except John Travolta.

@Raytrek, thank you for your advise. I've seen this movie few hours ago and now I don't know. Maybe it's same movie, maybe not. I think in movie which I've mentioned was sci-fi elements and there were happy end. Anyway, it's great movie and I enjoined every minute of watching.

Far shot, but this could also be Control from 2004 starring Ray Liotta.
It is a drug and not memory deletion, but everything else matches.

Lee Ray Oliver is a death row inmate who is given a lethal injection before a room of witnesses. He awakes in the morgue to find that he had only been administered saline and anaesthetic. A neuropharmacologist, Dr. Copeland, tells him that he has a choice: either agree to be a human subject for an experimental drug trial with potentially serious or fatal side effects, or he will receive a truly lethal injection.
Oliver opts for the drug trial, where he is administered a "calming" medicine on a daily basis and tested extensively to see if his sociopathic tendencies decrease. Twice, Oliver fakes being relaxed to lull the guards and scientists into a false sense of ease, whereupon he attempts an escape. First he asks for a smoke, second he talks to Dr. Copeland.
Over time, the medicine and psychological counseling do appear to lower his sociopathology, as measured physiologically and emotionally, and Oliver undergoes "phase two" of the procedure, where he is reintroduced into society, with a false identity and a changed appearance (tattoos and scars removed, dress and hairstyle change)...


I believe the film you are looking for is actually Primal Fear. It has to do with some amnesia, creating another violent identity and people using this to avoid death sentence in favor of psychiatric treatment. I would like to avoid other details for fear of spoiling the movie for everyone else here. Although there is no John Travolta, you might recognize Richard Gere and Edward Norton.
I would like to mention that I have not seen the movie yet, only read the book (captivating lecture) that it is based on some years ago and it seems to fit your description very good.

Mmm...to explain why this probably isn't it would be a spoiler, but this is a long shot.

@JohnP I do not see why this would be a long shot. It seems to me to fit the description. From my understanding, we are looking for some movie where a character has a multiple personality. So why doesn't this movie fit the profile? As a side note, please observe that the user does not specify anything about the ending.

Because Primal Fear was about the trial, not after the sentencing, and the multiple personality angle was vastly different, they weren't trying to treat it at all.

Note: I'm not dismissing it completely, just stating that it's a long shot. :)
